# How to use kotlin exposed upsert (Insert Or Update) functionality via DSL

Tags: kotlin, upsert, kotlin-exposed

How we can use kotlin exposed upsert functionality in DSL? there is some documentation on this but its very small and lacks a lot. Understaning how it works in code is hard too because it seems that internal API of library is exposed to user of library.
I have simple use case: in case of insert `save these for example 10 columns into database` and in case of update `update these 4 columns`. But I can't get it to work because upsert `onUpdate` parameter requires building a `Expression`. how to create this `onUpdate` is my problem and I don't know how to.

Here is my table:

```
object AccountTable : IdTable<String>(name = "Account") {
    val clientAccountNumber = varchar("clientAccountNumber", AccountId.LEN).entityId()
    override val id: Column<EntityID<String>> = clientAccountNumber

    val userId = uuid("userId").references(UserTable.id).nullable()
    val bourseCode = varchar("bourseCode", BourseCode.MAX_LEN)
    val firstName = varchar("firstName", Account.FIRST_NAME_MAX_LEN)
    val lastName = varchar("lastName", Account.LAST_NAME_MAX_LEN)
    val phoneNumber = varchar("phoneNumber", PhoneNumber.MAX_LEN)
    val nationalCode = varchar("nationalCode", NationalCode.MAX_LEN)
    val marketMakerFor = varchar("marketMakerFor", Account.MARKET_MAKER_MAX_LEN)
    val applyCommissionFeeFloor = bool("applyCommissionFeeFloor")
    val preview = bool("preview")
}
```

How we can implement this in exposed: in case of insert all columns should be provided for insert but in case of update only(firstName, LastName and phoneNumber) should be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented via kotlin exposed literals. there are some built-in literial to provide this functionality e.g stringLiteral, booleanLiteral etc. They are implementation of LiteralOp class that can be used to create those expressions required.

```kotlin
AccountTable.upsert(AccountTable.id,
                onUpdate = mutableListOf(
                        AccountTable.firstName to stringLiteral(account.firstName),
                        AccountTable.lastName to stringLiteral(account.lastName),
                        AccountTable.phoneNumber to stringLiteral(account.phoneNumber.value),
                        AccountTable.nationalCode to stringLiteral(account.nationalCode.value)
                )
        ) {
            it[id] = account.id
            it[firstName] = account.firstName
            it[lastName] = account.lastName
            it[phoneNumber] = account.phoneNumber.value
            it[nationalCode] = account.nationalCode.value
        }
```